# How should I structure a Rust project for solving small coding challenges?

Tags: rust, project-structure

I have been doing [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) problems (mathematical coding challenges) for a while.

In the past I have been coding them up in Python (where it is simple to have dozens of scripts in the same project). However, I am now redoing some of the challenges as I learn Rust. I have found it pretty awkward to work on these projects as I can't simply write a bunch of Rust programs in the same directory but it also seems very excessive to create a whole new Rust project for each program.

Can anyone recommend a good intermediary? Ideally I'm looking for something similar to the aforementioned Python project with a bunch of separate scripts.

Comment: You can have as many binaries as you want in a single project, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#binaries. The `path` property allows you to specify which source file corresponds to each binary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend this project structure for working through coding challenges:

```
/src/bin/problem-101.rs
/src/bin/problem-143.rs
/src/lib.rs
/Cargo.toml
```

Essentially just create a project like `cargo new --lib challenges`, create a `bin/` folder in `src/`, create separate source files for each problem in there, and off you go!

```
//! /src/bin/problem-101.rs
fn main() {
    println!("solution #101")
}
```

```
//! /src/bin/problem-143.rs
fn main() {
    println!("solution #143")
}
```

```
//! /src/lib.rs
pub fn add(left: usize, right: usize) -> usize {
    left + right
}
```

```toml
# Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "challenges"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
# dependencies are shared between all problems
```

This structure is easy to use and extend with small "scripts" because Rust source files in the `/src/bin` folder are automatically detected as binaries and do not need to be listed separately in `Cargo.toml`. You can run them directly:

```
> cargo run --bin problem-101
   Compiling challenges v0.1.0 (...\challenges)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.26s
     Running `target\debug\problem-101.exe`
solution #101
> cargo run --bin problem-143
   Compiling challenges v0.1.0 (...\challenges)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.32s
     Running `target\debug\problem-143.exe`
solution #143
```

Using a library as the root of the project allows you to share functions and logic between your problems very easily. Just import from the library like so:

```
use challenges::add;
```

The only step up from here would be to use [workspaces](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html) which would give you fine-grained dependencies for each problem, but that requires separate folders, separate `Cargo.toml`s, separate `src/` directories so you probably don't want that for simple coding challenges.